# React Native Android - How to be able to Scroll through TextInput

Tags: android, react-native, scrollview, textinput

I am creating a form and its style has labels at left and TextInputs at the right side as a requirement. So the problem that I have confronted with is that the scrolling is not possible when you touch to a TextInput somehow. Most of the users uses right side for scrolling so this is a major problem for me. Do you have an idea that would bring solution to this ?

Example code of the style just in case or maybe people can find something useful

```js
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', marginTop: 10, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }} >
                        <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignSelf: 'center', alignItems: 'center', width: W, height: HEIGHT / 18, borderWidth: 1 }}>
                            <Text adjustsFontSizeToFit
                                style={{ textAlign: 'center', color: 'black', }} >
                                Telefon Numarası
                            </Text>
                        </View>
                        <TextInput
                            ref={(node) => { this.phoneNumber = node; }}
                            dataDetectorTypes={['phoneNumber']}
                            blurOnSubmit={false}
                            keyboardType={'phone-pad'}
                           
                            defaultValue={this.props.data.plateInformation != null ? this.props.data.plateInformation.phoneNumber : ''}
                            returnKeyType={'go'}
                            onChangeText={this.props.changePhoneNumber}
                            keyboardAppearance={'dark'}
                            returnKeyLabel={'Devam'}
                            onSubmitEditing={() => this.carBrand.focus()}
                            style={{ color: 'green', textAlign: 'center', borderWidth: 1, width: W, height: HEIGHT / 18, margin: 'auto' }}
                        />
                    </View>
```

Comment: This is a issue in the platform of Android. You can track this issue with these links:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16206

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12167

Answer (score 2):

For some reason this worked for me: `multiline={true}`.

Not exactly sure why.
Stranger still, it will not work if you also have `keyboardType='numeric'`.

Comment: Yeah, I did the same in my implementation. Thank you for you answer but I will not mark as an answer thus someone can push fully working solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, add following props to TextInput

```
<TextInput
  ...
  maxHeight={<your height>}
  autoGrow={ false } />
```

Comment: Thank you for answer but it seems that TextInput does not have those props you have listed on the answer. Could you be more specific ?

Comment: Refer this link https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.50/textinput.html TextInput has all the props. make sure youre on Latest RN version

Comment: I have checked my React Native version and that is 0.50.4 . How possible do not I have these props on my TextInput ? I will figure it out.

Comment: I have upgraded my React but it seems that my TextInput still does not have those props in the version of 0.52.0. Sounds strange.

Comment: still these props I cant see in 0.68.5 @ozer